# Easiest way to print the head of a data in python?

Tags: python, pandas, head

I'm not defining my array with pandas, I'm using numpy to do it and I would like to know if there is any other way to print the first 5 rows of a data. Using pandas this is how I would do it: print(data.head()).

This is how i defined my data:

```
with open('B0_25.txt', 'r') as simulation_data:
simulation_data = [x.strip() for x in simulation_data if x.strip()]

data = [tuple(map(float, x.split())) for x in simulation_data[2:100]]  

x = [x[1] for x in data]
y = [x[2] for x in data]
z = [x[3] for x in data]
mx = [x[4] for x in data]
my = [x[5] for x in data]
mz = [x[6] for x in data]

mydata = np.array([x, y, z, mx, my, mz])
```

Comment: Try `print(mydata[:5, :])`

Comment: by doing that it did the opposite that i was expecting. the program printed 5 columns instead of all of the 6, and printed all of the rows. does that mean that my data is transposed? any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I wasn't thinking. What I wrote would work if you had a 2D array. What you have is a 1D array containing lists, so the 1st `:5` selects the first five entries of the array, while the 2nd `:` selects all columns of those first five entries.

Comment: The answer I just posted should work

Comment: Omg, I wrote this thinking that this was a 6D array. I thought that x, y, z, mx, my, mz was different dimensions in the array "mydata" . Can you please explain the difference? Because this is really importance since i'm working with dimensionality reduction. Thank you.

Comment: The dimensions of a numpy array are controlled through the "level of nesting" of the iterables you are using as input. This means that `[1, 2]` gives you a 1D array, `[[1,2],[5,4], [8,2]]` will give you a 2D array, `[[[1,2],[3,4]], [5,6],[7,8]]]` will give you a 3D array, etc.... In your case x, y, z, mx, my and mz are already 1D lists, and by putting them inside another list through [x, y, z, mx, my, mz] you are effectively creating a list with 2 levels of nesting, hence a 2D array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the transpose of mydata, otherwise x, y, z, mx, my, mz are the rows rather than the columns.

```
mydata = np.array([x, y, z, mx, my, mz]).T
print(mydata[:5, :])
```